# accessing a registry key throws an exception?

Tags: c#

I am trying to access a key in the following path in registry on widows 8:

> Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

and I am using the folowing in code to do that:

```
using (RegistryKey baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default))
{
    using (RegistryKey key = baseKey.OpenSubKey(startUpRegistryPath))
```

But this throws an exception:

> SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.

How do i gain write acccess to that path with C# code?

Thanks!

Comment: you do not have write access or no access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably need an [Application Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) requesting administrator privileges so your application can access the registry.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true"/>
```

The UAC disables applications from having rights to specific areas that are deemed "harmful"; among those are the registry and Program Files/Windows directories.

Comment: thank you, i did try that...but when i launch the exe it always gives a prompt saying " The requested operation requires elevation"

Comment: @user1202434: It's going to, unless you have UAC disabled. The warning is intended to protect the end-user. If you want to short-circuit it through development, run Visual Studio under administrator privileges so, while debugging, you won't be repeatedly confronted.

Comment: Just right click on application and choose Run as Administrator, If the exception still thrown, then manifest file can't help.